# PyQT classes e threads

Tags: multithreading, class, pyqt4

Hy,
i'm tryng to write a simple app with PyQT which basically display a map where a Thread class would write some text in a "console" which is a textbox, on the main GUI.
When i execute the code i've the following error:
type object 'GoogleMapsExec' has no attribute 'console'

This is my code:

```
class Modem(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
        a = "this is a thread"
        GoogleMapsExe.console.setText(a)



class GoogleMapsExec(QDialog, Ui_DialogGoogleMaps):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.MapView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("map.com"))
       #self.console.setText("line 1")

    @pyqtSignature("")
    def on_Button_clicked(self):
        t = Modem()
        t.start()


##d = threading.Thread(name='daemon', target=daemon)
##d.setDaemon(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    DialogGoogleMaps = GoogleMapsExec()
    DialogGoogleMaps.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What i'm not understanding? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to instantiate GoogleMapsExec before you can call instance methods, which is the source of your exception eg. `GoogleMapsExe().console.setText(a)`
2. More importantly, for threading with PyQt you need to your PyQt's [QThread](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qthread.html), not Python's threading module.